# Mysql query to select only one unique name on a criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this.

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+
| name       | hobby       | hobby_number |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
| jack       | sport       | 1            |
| marco      | skydiving   | 3            |
| alfonso    | driving     | 1            |
| marco      | learning    | 2            |
| jack       | dancing     | 2            |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to use sql select statement to select only one unique name.
The table I want may look like this:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+
| name       | hobby       | hobby_number |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
| jack       | sport       | 1            |
| marco      | learning    | 2            |
| alfonso    | driving     | 1            |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

What should sql query be?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t.* from your_table t
inner join
(
    select name, min(hobby_number) as minh
    from your_table
    group by name
) x on x.name = t.name and x.minh = t.hobby_number
```